# JMeter - localhost - wait for local server startup completed

Tags: jmeter, localhost

I have a JMeter script which tests a couple of requests against my local server running on localhost:9002. I let the tests run for 5 minutes.

As I want to do some automation I need the JMeter script to wait until my local server startup has completed (which will be around 10 minutes)

Is it possible to let my JMeter script wait until localhost:9002 is available and then start to fire the requests for 5 minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test/) to your Test Plan
2. Add [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) to the setUp Thread Group and use the following __groovy() function as the condition:

   ```
   ${__groovy(!vars.get('continue').equals('false'),)}
   ```
3. Add [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to your Test Plan and configure it like:

   [image]

   [image]
4. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the HTTP Request sampler and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   if (prev.isSuccessful()) {
       vars.put('continue', 'false')
   }
   ```

   [image]
5. That's it, While Controller will loop the HTTP Request sampler until it will be successful which means that your application is up and running.

   [image]

Comment: thanks, very good explaination.
do you know wheter I can trigger the startup of my local server (e. g. via shellscript) from within my JMeter script?

Comment: Sure, JMeter comes with [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) which can execute arbitrary command or program, check out [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter/) article for more details